# Number of columns in data file using STATS

Tags: gnuplot

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078933/plot-all-columns-in-a-file-using-gnuplot-without-specifying-number-of-columns), I'd like to determine the amount of columns in my file.

The file looks like this:

```
Header,,Header2,,Header3,,
1,2,3,4,5,6
11,12,13,14,15,16
```

When I now try to use the stats command:

```
stats 'data.dat'
max_col = STATS_columns
```

Gnuplot gives the error that there's `bad data on line 1 of file data.dat` which obviously is the header.
If I remove the header, everything's fine, but I'm planning on using `columnheader` for automated labelling (as discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818797/gnuplot-plotting-several-datasets-with-titles-from-one-file)) of the curves, so removing the header is not a solution.

If it matters: I'm working on a Windows-machine.

Comment: If you have a header in your data-file, you *have to* use `...title columnheader(N)`. Until you need this, comment the header!
**And don't forget** `set datafile separator ","` !

Comment: With gnuplot 5 you can try `stats 'data.dat' skip 1` (or `skip 2`, I'm not sure about the numbers)

Comment: using `stats 'data.dat' skip 1` works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As hinted in the comments, the solution is simply modifying the command like this:

```
stats 'data.dat' skip 1
max_col = STATS_columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `STATS_columns` will not necessarily give you the maximum number of columns in a file or datablock. Apparently, it will just give you the number of columns in the first data row. If following rows have more columns `stats` will not take this into account.

If you need to know the maximum number of columns of data which is not a regular table, the following code (tested in gnuplot 5.2.5) is counting the separators of all lines in a "irregular" datablock and tells you the maximum. Well, possible drawback: commented lines containing separators will also be included. A file has to be loaded to a datablock first.
I am happy to learn if there is a better way.

```
### maximum number of columns in datablock
reset session

$Data <<EOD
11  12  33
21  22  23  24  25
31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
41  42  43  44  45
51  52
EOD

# Method with stats
stats $Data nooutput
print "STATS_columns: ", STATS_columns

# Method with counting separators
CountChar(s,c) = int(sum[Count_i=1:strlen(s)] (s[Count_i:Count_i] eq c))
ColMax = 0
Separator = "\t"
do for [i=1:|$Data|] {
    ColCount = CountChar($Data[i],Separator)+1
    ColMax = (ColCount > ColMax ? ColCount : ColMax)
}
print "Maximum Columns: ", ColMax
### end of code
```

Result:

```
STATS_columns: 3
Maximum Columns: 9
```